# Mountain Lion on Intel Core 2 duo (2009 macbook pro)

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, macos

has anyone tested the new Mountain Lion on a 2008/2009 macbook?(aluminium) I've heard that with Lion some problems occured like mac becomes slow, battery life is halved etc. I'd like to know specific problems regarding updating from snow leopard to mountain lion on a 2008/2009 macbook pro with intel core 2 duo and 4GB ram, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed Mountain Lion on a Macbook Pro 3,1 (2007). "Over the top", so no clean install.

**Specs: 500 HDD, 2GB DDR2 RAM, 2.2 GHz C2D**

This is the oldest MBP which supports Lion. And it runs fine. No hiccups so far. It boots as fast as before (~1 min). It sleeps reliably. But I can't comment on the battery life yet.

Comment: Good! As soon as you can tell me something about battery life, please make a comment! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Mid 2009 MacBook Pro, 2.26GHz C2D, 8GB RAM. No battery issues. Mail works fine (3.5k emails on exchange), searching the mailbox is lightning fast.

Answer (score 0):

it seems i have battery problems too after updating sys from snow lepard to m.lion. Have a mid 2009 Macbook Pro core 2 duo and 4 GB Ram. Since i have upgraded i got the message "service battery" at the battery info and during normal usage the battery drains very fast.

Answer (score 0):

I have a 2009 MacBook Pro with 8GB of RAM. I installed Mountain Lion over a Snow Leopard install.. Mail and Finder seem much faster, but I haven't noticed any battery issues. However, battery life results are impacted by settings like Mail, Messages and Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I also have have a 2009 MacBook Pro with 8GB of RAM. The upgrade to ML from SL seems to have boosted my battery life, although the battery indicator does seem to fluctuate more than before. Everything runs very smoothly, which was a pleasant surprise. Safari is exceptionally fast on ML. Dictation also works well around 85% of the time for myself.